# Do animations keep playing after ViewController is dismissed?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, core-animation

I'm working on an interactive book for iPad, each page of the book has its individual ViewController. Each page has around twenty different `UIImageViews` with different animations each.

However, I'm suspecting that the animations are still playing after the View Controller is dismissed. For example, In some, I have set `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat` in their `options`, and in others and I set `1000` as their `repeatCount`.

Each view controller calls this:

```
-(void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    for(UIView *v in self.view.subviews){
        if([v isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
            [v.layer removeAllAnimations];
        }
    }
```

But it looks like they're still playing after it gets dismissed... Any thoughts?

Comment: It would surprise me if they played in the background.

Comment: You should be able to investigate if the animations are still on the view after it has disappeared by calling `animationKeys` on the layers. If it is nil then you don't have any animations after the view has disappeared (given that you gave your animations keys when adding them)